# ASP.NET using UrlHelper in ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to strongly type (such as it is) some URLs for a web app when I build a viewmodel.

So I have something like:

```
   new MyModel {
           Text = "Foo",
           Url = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("MyAction")
   }
```

This works just fine in a controller method, but I have another situation where I am not receiving the Request.Context because it's being called in another class.

Is there another way to do this so that I'm not using "magic strings" and/or relying on the context object?

Answer (score 1):

Use Reference

```
HttpContext.Current
```

which is derived from `system.web`. There for following code will work anywhere in your application.

```
UrlHelper objUrlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
objUrlHelper.Action("About");
```

Example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public string Link
    {
        get
        {
            UrlHelper objUrlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
            return objUrlHelper.Action("YourAction", "YourController", new { id = this.ID });
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel(int id)
    {
        this.ID = id;
    }
}
```